# Can I talk Java into printing to the console under Mountain Lion?

Tags: java, osx-mountain-lion, println, system.out

I'm using the good old `System.out.println` - approach to debug my Java application. Before I upgraded to Mac OS 10.8 this worked wonderfully. Now however my console wouldn't display anything. Apparently I'm not the first one to encounter this behavior - see http://www.mac-forums.com/forums/os-x-operating-system/280577-system-out-println-not-showing-console.html.

Does any of you guys know a way?

Comment: Did you try the "hello world" test described in the linked thread?

Comment: Does `java -version` produce any output to the console?

Comment: Actually, no, it doesn't! It does in the terminal, but not in the console (not sure I would expect it to, though). Thought you wondered if java is installed at all. The java project is fairly large und runs as expected, it's just that I can't debug it the way I could under 10.7.

Comment: By "the console" you mean Console.app, right? If so, I should mark this for deletion (duplicate):
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439629/how-do-i-enable-java-output-in-console-app-in-osx-10-8-3

Comment: Yes, I do mean the Console.app, so feel free to mark this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

`System.console()` returns null for me with mountain lion and java 6.

We have had to change our logging in our app to use `log4j` to output to `stdout` (which used to go to system.log prior to 10.8) **AND** produce our own log files in `~/Library/Logs` which can be seen in console.app under any version.

Doesn't appear to be a sandboxing issue as i'm not seeing any sandboxing errors. Prob more investigation needed to see what device is being handed to the jvm under 10.8. At a guess maybe its being handed `/dev/null` for logging by mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
System.console().printf("Hello World!");
```

Comment: Why the downvote? It's a perfectly fair question. Notice that RampantBadger's answer came 4 days later.