# How do I enable Java output in Console.app in OSX 10.8(.3)?

Tags: java, macos, debugging, console, output

I'm used to using Console.app to see System.err/out.println() output from my compiled Java applications.  I just installed a Java application on a new 10.8 machine, and now Console.app is mute.

How do I enable Java output in Console.app on 10.8?

I'm fiddling with Java Preferences, which I downloaded from [this link](http://appleupdate.centenary.usyd.edu.au/appleupdates/content/downloads/11/30/041-4540/6JfG7McpmBmS2nbCWvJXX9GQmYhYQ8dWQJ/JavaEssentials.pkg) (found on [this thread](https://forum.processing.org/topic/how-to-re-enable-java-1-6-on-mac-osx-mountain-lion)), but nothing seems to do the trick.